# How do I write an RSpec test to unit-test this interesting metaprogramming code?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, rspec, testing

Here's some simple code that, for each argument specified, will add specific get/set methods named after that argument. If you write `attr_option :foo, :bar`, then you will see `#foo/foo=` and `#bar/bar=` instance methods on `Config`:

```
module Configurator
  class Config
    def initialize()
      @options = {}
    end

    def self.attr_option(*args)
      args.each do |a|
        if not self.method_defined?(a)
          define_method "#{a}" do
            @options[:"#{a}"] ||= {}
          end

          define_method "#{a}=" do |v|
            @options[:"#{a}"] = v
          end
        else
          throw Exception.new("already have attr_option for #{a}")
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So far, so good. I want to write some RSpec tests to verify this code is actually doing what it's supposed to. But there's a problem! If I invoke `attr_option :foo` in one of the test methods, that method is now forever defined in Config. So a subsequent test will fail when it shouldn't, because `foo` is already defined:

```
  it "should support a specified option" do
    c = Configurator::Config
    c.attr_option :foo
    # ...
  end

  it "should support multiple options" do
    c = Configurator::Config
    c.attr_option :foo, :bar, :baz   # Error! :foo already defined
                                     # by a previous test.
    # ...
  end
```

Is there a way I can give each test an anonymous "clone" of the `Config` class which is independent of the others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One very simple way to "clone" your `Config` class is to simply subclass it with an anonymous class:

```
c = Class.new Configurator::Config
c.attr_option :foo

d = Class.new Configurator::Config
d.attr_option :foo, :bar
```

This runs for me without error.  This works because all instance variables and methods that get set are tied to the anonymous class instead of `Configurator::Config`.

The syntax `Class.new Foo` creates an anonymous class with `Foo` as a superclass.

Also, `throw`ing an `Exception` in Ruby is incorrect; `Exception`s are `raise`d.  `throw` is meant to be used like a `goto`, such as to break out of multiple nests.  Read [this Programming Ruby section](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/tut_exceptions.html) for a good explanation on the differences.

As another style nitpick, try not to use `if not ...` in Ruby.  That's what `unless` is for.  But unless-else is poor style as well.  I'd rewrite the inside of your `args.each` block as:

```
raise "already have attr_option for #{a}" if self.method_defined?(a)
define_method "#{a}" do
  @options[:"#{a}"] ||= {}
end

define_method "#{a}=" do |v|
  @options[:"#{a}"] = v
end
```

Comment: +1 for solid advice and a novel approach; I would not have thought of creating the anonymous classes and was pondering something like creating an anonymous module with the class and then destroying it. This is clearly a better solution.